# Button VS Image buttons in JAVA

Tags: java, swing, listener, jbutton, jlabel

Recently I found out that I can use my images as buttons with mouse listener.
What is the main difference between using buttons and images as buttons. What is the main drawback of this option?

Button:

```
JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("Button");
btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    //Do something          
  }
});
```

Image:

```
getJlabel().addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
  @Override
  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {    
    //Do something
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although both of them provide similar functionalities, I think that most users are not accustomed to such a thing.

To the average user (in my opinion at least), buttons should be clicked and images should be looked at. It is like the image provides a means to the user to understand and the button provides a means for the user to act.

You could throw in Images in JButtons (as explained [here](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Swing-Tutorial/Swing-Tutorial-JButton.html)), but that being said, I think that from a User Experience point of view you should not use images as buttons unless you really have to, and when you do, I think that you should include specific instructions.

Answer (score 1):

The JButton provides animation (during clicking and releasing), different looks for different states (like when it's not enabled) and other things one expects from an actual "push button".
You can add the these (or some of these) functionalities to an image according to your requirements using a mouse listener.
It all depends on what you want and how much code are you willing to write by hand.

FYI, the images can be added to JButtons (mainly for the purpose of icons).